# Packets drop at Open vSwitch

Tags: openstack, packets

In our OpenStack environment, we did see huge packets lost. Then we found packets were dropped at Open vSwitch. Could someone give clue how to improve the situation?

[bscuser@compute-4 ~]$ sudo ovs-ofctl dump-ports br-int vhub97ae049-a2
OFPST_PORT reply (xid=0x4): 1 ports
  port "vhub97ae049-a2": rx pkts=12472105, bytes=1647807101, drop=0, errs=0, frame=?, over=?, crc=?
           tx pkts=83585797, bytes=77693614917, drop=4643534, errs=?, coll=?

[root@compute1 ~]# ovs-ofctl show br-int
OFPT_FEATURES_REPLY (xid=0x2): dpid:0000c272e446ba49
n_tables:254, n_buffers:0

And n_buffers is 0, is it normal? I searched on web, it seems all the result are 256. But I don't know how to change it.

Thank you in advance.